# CORS blocks mutation in GraphQL Yoga

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, react-apollo, prisma-graphql

I am working here with a graphql prisma backend and a graphql yoga express server on top of that. In the frontend, I am trying to call a signout mutation but its blocked by the CORS policy. Though I have added cors settings in my graphql yoga server, I keep getting this error. GraphQL Queries are working fine but Mutations are being blocked. My frontend URL is 'http://localhost:7777' and yoga server is running at 'http://localhost:4444/'. The Error was:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4444/' from origin 'http://localhost:7777' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[Network error]: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

GraphQL Yoga Server Cors Config:

```
server.start(
{
    cors: {
        credentials: true,
        origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL],
    },
},
deets => {
    console.log(
        `Server is now running on port http://localhost:${deets.port}`
    );
}
);
```

Mutation:

```
// import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { CURRENT_USER_QUERY } from './User';
import { log } from 'util';

const SIGN_OUT_MUTATION = gql`
mutation SIGN_OUT_MUTATION {
    signout {
        message
    }
}
`;

const SignOutBtn = styled.button`
color: ${props => props.theme.textMedium};
padding: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-family: garamond-light;
border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.textMedium};
border-radius: 5px;
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
transition: color 0.5s ease;
:hover {
    background: ${props => props.theme.textMedium};
    color: ${props => props.theme.white};
}
`;

const Signout = props => (
<Mutation
    mutation={SIGN_OUT_MUTATION}
    refetchQueries={[{ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY }]}
>
    {signout => (
        <SignOutBtn
            onClick={() => {
                console.log("comes here")
                signout();
            }}
        >
            Sign Out
        </SignOutBtn>
    )}
</Mutation>
);
export default Signout;
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the code you shared. Could you provide a minimum reproduciable repository for us to investigate more?

Comment: @Errorname Thanks for trying to help and you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/aravind-kr/). The repo won't be having environment files. If you are in need of those, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but there is too much files to analyse. Could you create a repository with only the files necessary to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to write a middleware that sets appropriate response headers so that the fetch doesn't fail.

```
server.express.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:7777');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});
```

The above is the yoga express server middleware used to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you keep the `cors: {credentials: true,origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,},` on the server?

Comment: @ChanceSmith Yes I tried that, but it wasn't working for me. I have posted the same config in the question as well. Let me know if I have done something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having the same issue, but now wondering if you left that object in or not. ‍♂️

Comment: Can you share more of the code above this block? I've found several implementations of this, but none that really explain how the `.express.use` part is set up. [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/redliz5808/pen/NWXLEbq) is what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was pass the origin an array of string values. As well as set the new origin PAST_FRONTEND_URL in heroku

```js
server.start(
  {
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, process.env.PAST_FRONTEND_URL],
    },
  },
  deets => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on port http://localhost:${deets.port}`);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was solved with this

```js
server.start(
  {
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL],
      methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
      preflightContinue: false,
      optionsSuccessStatus: 204
    }
  },
  server => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost/${server.port}`);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this middleware helped in my case:

```
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Server Application must add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: YOUR_DOMAIN` to the response header and the browser will not complain about it.

**You can use a middleware to achieve it.**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

*OR*

```
const cors =  require('cors')
const corsOptions = {
    origin: [
        
        "http://YOUR-DOMAIN"
    ],
    credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

**But wait !! I already done these steps but still the problem exist ;(**

if after these steps the issue still exist.

then it's because of **corrupted response**.

maybe your server **throw an exception** while sending the response or maybe it **restart** and the response not sent to client completely. or maybe some problem with your ISP or VPN which block some requests. :)